# Perguntas duplicatas não aceitam ser fechadas

Tags: debate, fechamento

Vi estas duas perguntas https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23204/m%C3%BAltiplos-uploads-via-ajax e [Uploads de arquivos via ajax](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23235/uploads-de-arquivos-via-ajax#23235) que são claramente perguntas duplicadas.

O utilizador até criou um utilizador novo para fazer a pergunta eheheh.

A pergunta não dá para ser considerada duplicata:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Como fazer nestas situações? Será que posso ter 500 perguntas iguais no SOPT sem serem fechadas por causa desse motivo?

Answer (score 7):

Isso é para evitar que perguntas sejam fechadas sem apontar para uma *resposta* existente (a menos que as duas perguntas em jogo sejam do mesmo autor).

O procedimento nesses casos é sinalizar a pergunta, explicando a situação. Essa restrição de fechamento não se aplica aos moderadores, que tomarão a decisão final. Neste caso, fechei a pergunta.

Comment: Esclarecido bfvarreto :)