# Duplicar perguntas sem resposta de um mesmo usuário

Tags: debate, suporte

Notei que não é possível marcar como duplicata uma pergunta se a outra pergunta não tiver ao menos uma resposta, mas penso que se ambas perguntas forem da mesma pessoa não deveria haver esta restrição, por exemplo:

- (postada as 18:26) [Como excluir div pelo nome da classe usando WebBrowser?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122481/3635)
- (postada as 18:50) https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122483/3635

Ou então o que seria melhor, sinalizar pra remover uma delas (ocultar)?

Comment: Depois de um tempo uma pergunta sem respostas ou sem votos é automaticamente removida.

Comment: Como não? Acabei de votar como duplicata! Segundo o Math me falou uma vez. só não é possivel se for de usuarios diferentes, do mesmo, não importa se está sem resposta.

Comment: @DiegoF você votou como duplicata de uma outra pergunta que não é do mesmo usuário.

Comment: Na verdade, eu entrei nos links que você citou, na pergunta mais nova, cliquei em *fechar* e selecionei *duplicata de...*

Comment: ignora, selecionei a pergunta errada, e essa já tinha resposta, por isso que deu.

Comment: @rray sim o "RemovedAbandonedClosed"

Comment: @Gulherme Apesar de aparentemente ser a mesma pessoa, note que estão diferentes os usuários. Nada que um flag pra moderação não resolva.

Comment: @bacco entendi, foi confusão minha :)

Comment: Ainda acha relevante a tag [meta-tag:novo-recurso] na sua pergunta?

Comment: @Math eu ainda não havia tido tempo pra verificar, fiquei sem entender se é possivel duplicar perguntas de um mesmo usuário, mesmo as situação ali da pergunta citada sendo diferente.

Comment: Se for do mesmo usuário dá para fechar sim, uma segunda palavra [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1650/3117). No caso em questão eu solicitei o merge dos usuários, mas a solução mais rápida para casos assim é pedir para o moderador fechar mesmo. Orientar o usuário também pode ser uma boa opção, mas não dá pra ter certeza que ele vai entender.

Comment: Opa blz, obrigado @Math!

Comment: @math Adiciona como resposta ;)

Comment: @Gabe  beleuza ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for do mesmo usuário dá para fechar sim, uma segunda palavra [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1650/3117).

No caso em questão acabaram fechando como duplicada de outra pergunta, tudo bem. Além disso eu solicitei o merge das contas pois era o mesmo usuário mas com duas contas diferentes.

A solução mais rápida para casos assim é pedir para o moderador fechar. Orientar o usuário também pode ser uma boa opção, mas não dá pra ter certeza que ele vai entender.