# O que fazer quando não há certeza que é mesmo usuário?

Tags: suporte

As seguintes perguntas são muito similares e possuem usuários com nomes iguais (Julia):

- [segmentação de imagens com texto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338425/segmenta%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-imagens-com-texto)
- [Segmentar texto separar linhas e parágrafos [pendente]](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/338504/segmentar-texto-separar-linhas-e-par%C3%A1grafos)

Mas os códigos não são exatamente iguais, o que fazer nesta situação?

Pois uma pergunta foi fechada porque não estava clara o suficiente, foi perguntado somente com o código.

A outra possui um pouco de explicação. Mas ambas são sobre o mesmo assunto, utilizando as mesmas bibliotecas e a função `dilatar` é a mesma.

Parece que o usuário perdeu a senha ou não conseguiu realizar o Log-in de alguma forma e fez duas perguntas.

A pergunta que está aberta foi feita primeiro, então possivelmente, não haverá nenhum feedback do OP

Li esta pergunta meta: [Duplicar perguntas sem resposta de um mesmo usuário](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4975/duplicar-perguntas-sem-resposta-de-um-mesmo-usu%C3%A1rio)

Mas não tenho certeza se é o mesmo usuário.

**Como proceder nestes casos?**

Comment: Agora vi que a função `dilatar` é a mesma, pode ser de algum tutorial da internet ou muito provavelmente o mesmo usuário.

Comment: Pergunte. Você pode comentar na pergunta mais nova como "foi você que postou essa outra pergunta?" e se foi você pode sinalizar para a moderação unir as duas contas.

Comment: Sendo do mesmo usuário ou não, se as perguntas são muito parecidas e uma resposta responder a ambas, deve ser marcado como duplicata, não?

Comment: Sim, mas a pergunta já está pendente. E na primeira pergunta o usuário provavelmente abandonou e não voltará. Pois entrou com outra conta.

Comment: Na dúvida, sempre sinalize. De fato tudo indica ser a mesma pessoa, e solicitei aos CMs que mesclem as contas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> As seguintes perguntas são muito similares e possuem usuários com nomes iguais (Julia)

De fato, tudo indica que são o mesmo usuário.

> Mas os códigos não são exatamente iguais, o que fazer nesta situação?

Na dúvida, pergunte. Se olhar os usuários verá que um possui registro e outro não. Isso acontece direto aqui, pois para perguntar não é exigido o cadastro. Você pode perguntar como "Convidado", indicando apenas um nome e um e-mail. Provavelmente quando ela quis efetuar, de fato, o cadastro, informou outra conta de e-mail e, assim, o sistema não identificou a conta de convidado dela.

Você pode sinalizar para a moderação descrevendo isso, mas eu costumo perguntar antes. Um simples comentário como "é você nessa outra pergunta?" já responderia todas as dúvidas. Se for o mesmo usuário, os moderadores podem pedir para os gerentes de comunidade mesclar as duas contas em uma manualmente.

A opção "Sinalizar para a moderação" não é só para casos críticos, mas sim para *qualquer coisa* que não seja atendida pelas outras opções. É comum sinalizarmos para moderação, por exemplo, casos em que o autor coloca dados sensíveis, como senhas, na pergunta ou quando há guerra de edições em que o AP fica revertendo edições úteis.

Mas também não digo para ficar sinalizando qualquer coisa para eles :D Se nossas filas de análise são grandes, imagina a deles... Se não for nada muito crítico, como esse caso, o melhor é pedir aqui no Meta mesmo, tal como fez.